# How to format a Google Calender API request using HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-calendar-api, httparty

I am getting the following error when I make a request to the Google Calendar API.

```
{"error"=>{"errors"=>[{"domain"=>"global", "reason"=>"required", "message"=>"Missing end time."}], "code"=>400, "message"=>"Missing end time."}}
```

What is wrong with my formatting? I've tried a ton of different layouts and can't seem to find much information about using HTTParty to make a request to a Google API.

```
results = HTTParty.post("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key=#{Rails.application.secrets.google_api_key}",
  :headers => {
    "Authorization" => "Bearer #{response["access_token"]}"
  },
  :query => {
    "end": {
      "dateTime" => "2015-05-29T09:00:00-08:00",
      "timeZone" => "America/Los_Angeles"
    },
    "start": {
      "dateTime" => "2015-05-29T09:00:00-07:00",
      "timeZone" => "America/Los_Angeles"
    },
    "summary": "TEST POST"
  }
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you trying to add events for the previous month?? You can add only future events not the past ones. Try changing the dates. you can try sample request here https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working. Turns out I should be sending a :body key instead of a :query key. Also, the header has to state that the format is JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. I needed to use a `:body` key and also specify JSON in the header

```
results = HTTParty.post("https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key=#{Rails.application.secrets.google_api_key}",
  :headers => {
    "Authorization" => "Bearer #{response["access_token"]}",
    "Content-Type" => "application/json"
  },
  :body => {
    "end": {
      "dateTime" => "2015-05-29T09:00:00-08:00",
      "timeZone" => "America/Los_Angeles"
    },
    "start": {
      "dateTime" => "2015-05-29T09:00:00-07:00",
      "timeZone" => "America/Los_Angeles"
    },
    "summary": "TEST POST"
  }
)
```